# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-9.04

How can I upgrade Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: System->Administration->Update Manager does not show new distribution?

Comment: U can check the link provided in my answer. It talks specifically about 9.04->9.10 upgradation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/karmic/beta) page on Ubuntu site. It talks specifically about upgrading 9.04 to 9.10.
(Also make sure you do not install it in production. I think its in beta)

Comment: That is an older page. Karmic (9.10) is beta now: http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/karmic/beta

Comment: Thanks nagul. I edited my answer to reflect the new link