# Update to Ubuntu 9.10 from Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade from Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10](https://superuser.com/questions/51619/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-9-04-to-ubuntu-9-10)

What are the steps to follow to upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10 as seamless as possible?

I have just installed 9.04 and although it was pretty easy, I don't want to do a clean installation of it to upgrade to 9.10 ( I would have to backup what I've done etc )

**EDIT**

You said there should be a button, there it is:

[image]

Comment: BTW if anyone is interested on this, I did rollback the upgrade because the graphics effects were not working as they did on 9.04 :(

Comment: How do you do the rollback?

Comment: I might need to because the wireless isn't working

Comment: @Dynamic I : Ouh.. pretty "rudimentary" :(  I insert the Ubuntu 9.04 disc and click on installl :(  That erased everything and now I enjoy staying on 9.04, the sound, graphics, wireless, everything works just fine.

Comment: There are probably different PPAs, you could get rid of the newer ones, replace the older ones, and then do su apt-get update && su apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the system Menu Go to Administration and Click on update manager there should be a button to click to upgrade to 9.10. I upgraded to the RC through this method and everything works as it should, be warned this process takes a bit of time to complete.

Answer (score 5):

Read [this official manual](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading). It'll help you.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `System -> Administration -> Update Manager` and just click "Upgrade". This *should* not cause you any troubles.

I haven't upgraded myself though, and I'll wait at least a month. Of course somebody will need to be the first, but if you're not in a hurry, and your current system runs fine, then you may just as well wait a bit. Unless there's something in the new release which you'd like to use, of course.

Note that a fresh installation of 9.10 allows you to use the [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) file system. <strike>With an upgrade this is not possible of course.</strike> You can also [convert ex3 to ex4 in place](http://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto#Converting_an_ext3_filesystem_to_ext4), but this is more of a hassle. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/453579) about 
corruption of large files when using ext4 though, so anyone doing a fresh install I'd recommend to *not* use the default ext4, but instead stick with [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3), one more time.