# Can I upgrade to the new Ubuntu 10 from Ubuntu 9.10 without formatting my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, upgrade, ubuntu-10.04

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you currently running Ubuntu? Or Windows? Or something else?

Comment: Then my answer is the easiest way to proceed ;) Considering you have GUI installed...

Comment: Also somewhat related: http://superuser.com/questions/62594/update-to-ubuntu-9-10-from-ubuntu-9-04

Comment: Yeah this is what I was talking about. I'll add it to my post, thank.

Comment: The update-manager should offer the option at the top of the list of package updates next time it runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have it already, you gonna need a free partition on your harddrive to install it beside your current OS. If you need to create a partition, Windows Seven (if you have Windows 7) allow you to shrink a partition so you'll be able to create some place for Ubuntu.

If you already have it , just go in Updater Manager panel and you'll have an option to upgrade to 10.04 LTS on top of it.

More details here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades#Upgrade%20from%209.10%20to%2010.04%20LTS

**Update : (thanks to [th3dude](https://superuser.com/users/4626/th3dude) )**

Could check this out too that outline exactly what I'm talking about :

[Update to Ubuntu 9.10 from Ubuntu 9.04](https://superuser.com/questions/62594/update-to-ubuntu-9-10-from-ubuntu-9-04)

Comment: You are assuming they are already running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Update Manager as specified in [Julien's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/137903/can-i-upgrade-to-the-new-ubuntu-10-from-ubuntu-9-10-without-formatting-my-compute/137904#137904), or from a terminal you can use:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type "update-manager -c", and the update manager will offer you to upgrade your Ubuntu version.

Comment: You are assuming they are running Ubuntu already.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from a terminal will work fine too :)

Comment: @Sathya: No, you would need to edit the package sources first. But that's not recommended as it isn't officially supported and may or may not fail.

Comment: @Julien Nicoulaud: don't use -d as this will upgrade to the latest devel release is possible. Use -c instead.

Comment: Hum yes, I did not notice Ubuntu 10.04 was released already. edited.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading

Answer (score 0):

Manual upgrade from Karmic to Lucid from the command line:

```
sudo sed -i 's/karmic/lucid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```